Pass NULL if bindParam() or bindValue() having empty variable
I have been struggling for 3 days but cannot get a simple solution.
    $asup = $connection->prepare(' 
                                    update company_assign set

                            post        =   :post,
                            shift_start =   :shift_start,
                            shift_end   =   :shift_end,
                                                                            
                    ');

$asup->bindParam(':post', $_POST['post']);
$asup->bindParam(':shift_start', $_POST['start']);
$asup->bindParam(':shift_end', $_POST['end']);
$asup->execute();

It's Working Perfectly, But I want to Pass NULL if any of $_POST arrary having NULL or Empty member.
Please help me to define correct binding statement. Previous days it seemed like this:
$asup->bindParam(':shift_start', $_POST['start'], NULL);

But now it's not working with PHP 8.1, please share if you have any idea. Thanks

HTTP post cannot convey NULL values

use this to set NULL parameter
$asup->bindParam(':shift_end', $shift_end, $shift_end === NULL ? PDO::PARAM_NULL : PDO::PARAM_STR);


this code makes no sense, as it doesn't do anything that the code in the OP already does

Yes exactly, I am looking like this.... But if it works..
